# Rewrite URL in new way

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a product gallery. While the detail page link of every product is:

```
<a href="http://productgallery.com/product.php?productid=<?php echo recordset['product_id'];?>"><?php echo recordset['product_name'];?></a>
```

so the web url is coming like:

```
http://productgallery.com/product.php?productid=008
```

etc.

suppose, the name of the product id "008" is "Baseball Cap", which is in the database too.
now, I wish to rewrite the url as like as:

```
http://productgallery.com/product/baseball-cap
```

how is it possible using [.htaccess]? please help me.

---

please note that, I **do not** wish to go like

```
http://productgallery.com/product/008
```

When the link is:

```
http://productgallery.com/product.php?productid=008
```

and I have restriction to send **only** "productid" as a GET parameter.
but I wish to go like

```
http://productgallery.com/product/baseball-cap
```

now, the product name "baseball-cap" is coming from the database.

This is what I am asking. Can anyone help me this.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the product id inside of product title. for example you can use this pattern:

```
http://productgallery.com/product/008-baseball-cap
```

and change htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product\/([^\\/]*)-([^\\/]*)$ product.php?productid=$1 [NC,QSA]
```